# javascript variable setting

Tags: javascript

I have a small if statement that runs when a function is run. The issue is that the variable timeout_value is always defined as 0 even after the if statement executes successfully. What am I doing wrong?

```
//update on interval
var timeout_value=0;
        //set interval based on number of users
if (json.countusers==2 && timeout_value!=3){
    alert(timeout_value);
    timeoutID2 = setInterval(refresh, 3000);
    timeout_value=3;
}
```

Comment: What does "refresh()" look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you defining `var timeout_value=0;` in the right scope?  Move it out of your method.

Answer (score 1):

Do you call this from inside a function? `var` makes the variable local, so it is not available in the global scope.